# read csv file from list but add the filename as identifier

Tags: r, readr

I have list of csv files. I could read them all using `read_csv`.

But I would like to add the filename as identifier. How do I do it ?

```
library(tidyverse)

# read file names
csv_filenames <- list.files(path = "OMITTED FOR THIS EXAMPLE", 
                            full.names = TRUE)


###
csv_filenames are "One.csv", "Two.csv", "Three.csv", ....
###

# read csv files
df <- read_csv(csv_filenames)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_csv` has an argument `id =` ; if you specify "path", you get a column named "path" with the file names:

```
csv_data <- read_csv(csv_filenames, id = "path")
```

If you wanted just the base file name, you could add a `dplyr::mutate` step:

```
library(dplyr)
csv_data <- read_csv(csv_filenames, id = "path") %>%
  mutate(path = basename(path))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `assign` with `basename` in a `for` loop.

```
for(i in seq_along(csv_filenames)){
  assign(basename(csv_filenames)[i], read.csv(csv_filenames[i]))
}
```

Using `basename` will assign a new object in the global environment with the name of the file in the folder (not the whole file path obtained with `full.names = TRUE`).

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

# list of file names
file_list <- list.files(path = "path/to/csv/files", pattern = "*.csv")

# read in all files and add the file name as an additional column
data_list <- lapply(file_list, function(x) {
  data <- read.csv(file = x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(file_name = x)
  return(data)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

With R base

```
csv_files <- lapply(csv_filenames, read.csv)
file_names <- sub("\\..*", "", basename(csv_filenames))
out <- lapply(1:length(csv_files), function(i){
  transform(csv_files[[i]],  file_name = file_names[i])
})
do.call(rbind, out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `cbind` the `basename`s, actually.

```
lapply(csv_filenames, \(x) cbind(read.csv(x), file=basename(x))) |> do.call(what=rbind)
#   X1 X2 X3 X4      file
# 1  1  4  7 10 file1.csv
# 2  2  5  8 11 file1.csv
# 3  3  6  9 12 file1.csv
# 4  1  4  7 10 file2.csv
# 5  2  5  8 11 file2.csv
# 6  3  6  9 12 file2.csv
# 7  1  4  7 10 file3.csv
# 8  2  5  8 11 file3.csv
# 9  3  6  9 12 file3.csv
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
path <- '/what/so/ever'
lapply(1:3, \(i) write.csv(dat, paste0(path, '/tmp/file', i, '.csv'), row.names=F))
csv_filenames <- list.files(paste0(path, "/tmp"), full.names=TRUE)
```